# regex match word boundary

Tags: regex

This seems like a simple question. I have this string:

```
Hi there. This is a @hello test.
```

I would like to do a word boundary match for the literal value `@hello`. I tried "`\b\@hello\b`" as the regex search but it's not working. What am I doing wrong here? It seems like `@` is not treated as a word boundary because when I do `\bhello\b`, the regex will match the entire  substring of `@hello`?

Answer (score 2):

You may use a whitespace boundary on the LHS of the `@` symbol:

```
(?<!\S)@hello\b
```

Here is a working [demo](https://regex101.com/r/Khv6Qj/1).  More generally, you may wish to use something more generic like:

```
(?<!\S)@\w+
```